# react passing object of function to default store in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-redux

hi everyone i have some reducers and I'm passing a function in object
other parameter are working but functions does not work
i got these warning::

Warning: React does not recognize the `sidebarState` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `sidebarstate` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

it's my code

```
bgColor: function (){
                return this.SidebarBgColor;
            },
```

bgColor dose not work

```
export const defaultStore = {
    token: false,
    user: false,
    cart: {},
    design: {
        designColor: "#49ff03",
        SidebarBgColor: "#3668cf",
        bgColor: function (){
            return this.SidebarBgColor;
        },
        // bgColor: "#4e1212",
        textBaseColor: "#f3ecec",
    },
    componentDisplay: {
        sidebarDisplay:"maximize",
    }
}

export default function designReducer(state = test(), action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "changeDesign" :
            console.log("yeah")
            state = {
                ...state,
                design: {
                    designColor: action.payload.designColor,
                    bgColor: action.payload.bgColor,
                    textBaseColor: action.payload.textBaseColor,
                }
            }
            console.log(state);
            return state;


        case "randomDesign" :
            console.log("yeah")

            let keys = Object.keys(cssColor);
            let designColor = cssColor[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
            let bgColor = cssColor[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
            let textBaseColor = cssColor[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];

            state = {
                ...state,
                design: {
                    designColor: designColor,
                    bgColor: bgColor,
                    textBaseColor: textBaseColor,
                }
            }
            console.log(state);
            return state;


        case "lightDesign" :
            state = {
                ...state,
                design: {
                    designColor: cssColor.blueviolet,
                    bgColor: cssColor.lightyellow,
                    textBaseColor: cssColor.darkcyan,
                }
            }
            console.log(state);
            return state;
        case "darkDesign" :
            state = {
                ...state,
                design: {
                    designColor: cssColor.snow,
                    bgColor: cssColor.black,
                    textBaseColor: cssColor.whitesmoke,
                }
            }
            console.log(state);
            return state;


        default:
            return state;
    }


}
```

sidebar::

```
 import '../css/sidebar.css';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {
    changeDesignAction,
    darkDesignAction,
    lightDesignAction,
    randomDesignAction
} from "../App/Reducer/designReducer";
import {AiFillHome, BiUpArrow, FaAccessibleIcon, IoClose} from "react-icons/all";
import {useState} from "react";
import {
    changeSidebarDisplayAction,
    maximizeSidebarDisplayAction,
    minimizeSidebarDisplayAction
} from "../App/Reducer/componentDisplayReducer";
import {Button} from "@mui/material";
import SidebarResponsiveButton from "../Components/SidebarResponsiveButton";

function Sidebar(props) {
    const [sidebarDisplay, setSidebarDisplay] = useState("true");
    console.log(props.sidebarState)

    function sidebarWidth() {
        switch (props.sidebarState) {
            case "false":
                return 0
            case "minimize":
                return "5vw"
            case "maximize":
                return "20vw"
            default:
                return "20vw"

        }
    }

    function sidebarArrowBtn() {
        switch (props.sidebarState) {

            case "minimize":
                return (
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                        props.maximizeSidebarDisplayAction();
                    }}> « </Button>
                )
            default:
                return (
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                        props.minimizeSidebarDisplayAction();
                    }}> » </Button>
                )

        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div className={"hqSidebar " + (props.sidebarState ? 'd-block' : "d-none")}
                 style={{
                     backgroundColor: props.designState.bgColor, color: props.designState.textBaseColor,
                     width: sidebarWidth()
                 }}>
                <div className="" onClick={() => {
                    props.changeSidebarDisplayAction();
                }}>
                    <IoClose/>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div className={"p-3 " + (props.sidebarState === "minimize" ? 'text-center' : "text-right")}>
                    <SidebarResponsiveButton className="sidebarItem" icon={<AiFillHome/>}> صفحه اصلی </SidebarResponsiveButton>
                    <SidebarResponsiveButton icon={<BiUpArrow/>}>item 2</SidebarResponsiveButton>
                    <SidebarResponsiveButton icon={<BiUpArrow/>}>item 3</SidebarResponsiveButton>
                    <SidebarResponsiveButton icon={<BiUpArrow/>}>test</SidebarResponsiveButton>
                    {sidebarArrowBtn()}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

function mapStateToProps(storeState) {
    return {
        designState: storeState.designStore.design,
        sidebarState: storeState.componentDisplayStore.componentDisplay.sidebarDisplay

    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    changeDesignAction,
    lightDesignAction,
    darkDesignAction,
    randomDesignAction,
    changeSidebarDisplayAction,
    maximizeSidebarDisplayAction,
    minimizeSidebarDisplayA
```

Comment: From where are you setting this and what is the value? `this.SidebarBgColor`

Comment: it's on  sidebar component's mapStateToProps  ,  function mapStateToProps(storeState) {
    return {
        designState: storeState.designStore.design,
        sidebarState: storeState.componentDisplayStore.componentDisplay.sidebarDisplay

    }
}